# How to hide stack navigation header from a single screen in react-navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

My app has 5 components (screens), I am using stack navigation version 5, I need the headers for all screens except one screen, I tried to do this via option inside screens like this:

This is my code:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const MainStack = () => ({
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="MyTabs" component={MyTabs} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Direct" component={Direct} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Like" component={Like} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
)}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the header options inside the component using ```static navigationOptions = { header:null }```. I am not sure if it will work on React Navigation v5.

Comment: No buddy, ```static navigationOptions``` doesn't work in version 5

Comment: Oops! Sorry then. I haven't yet moved to V5! Anyways, good luck :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use `options={{ headerShown: false }}`

Comment: thanks worked for me "navigationOptions becomes options prop on Screen" in v5

Answer (score 5):

1. in your navigation `options={{ headerShown: false }}`
2. from your component `navigation.setOptions({ headerShown: false })`